# How to call a python script from another python script with class object as an argument wait for it to finish

Tags: python-3.x

I have script a.py as

```
from my_obj import MYObj
   
def setup(my:MyObj = None):
    my.get_val()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arguments")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--my", type=str, default=MyClass, required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    setup(args.my)
```

script my_obj.py

```
from second_class inport SecondClass

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s_class = SecondClass()
    
    def execute_a_script(self):
        # HERE I NEED TO EXECUTE a.py and pass self.s_class to it also wait for script a.py to finish execution
```

I looked at the subprocess but I can't pass an object as an argument. There is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need argument parsing, you can just use `import`.

In your *my_obj.py* script:

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s_class = SecondClass()
    
    def execute_a_script(self):
        import a
        a.process(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyObj()
    obj.execute_a_script()
```

In your *a.py* script:

```
def process(obj: MyObj):
    print(obj.s_class)
    # Do your processing here
```

Your project structure should be like this:

```
.
├── a.py
└── my_obj.py
```

Then you can run

```
python my_obj.py
```